# jQuery draggable won't automatically scroll iframe down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe with several draggable divs inside. When dragging the items I want the iframe to automatically scroll up and down when it needs to, however it currently only scrolls up. I have tried it with the scroll option set to true however this doesn't work.

iFrame page is the following repeated enough to allow the page to scroll (https://jsfiddle.net/zhm6qjaz/):

```
<div class="block-style">
    Header
</div>
```

The main page code ( https://jsfiddle.net/huLr2zkv/ ):

```
<iframe id="editor-frame" src="https://jsfiddle.net/zhm6qjaz/show" style="height:500px; width:100%; border:none;"></iframe>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#editor-frame').load(function (event) {

        var iframe = $('#editor-frame').contents();

        iframe.find('.block-style').draggable({
            delay: 200,
            helper: "clone",
            iframeFix: true,
            iframeOffset: $('#editor-frame').offset(),
            appendTo: 'parent.body',
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            },
            drag: function (event, ui) {
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
        });

        iframe.find('.block-style', window.top.document).droppable({
            tolerance: "pointer",
            iframeFix: true,
            over: function (event, ui) {
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {               
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
            }
        });

    });

});</script>
```

I'm not sure what else to try, my guess is that this is not the expected behaviour and that when dragging down in the iframe it should automatically scroll?

Comment: Did you fond solution for this problem?